# NelmioApiDocBundle negative path_patterns

Tags: regex, symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

Right now I try to create an API documentation in Symfony 3 with the NelmioApiDocBundle. So far everything works as described in the given symfony documentation.

Now I'd like to remove the _error and _profiler routes from the swagger docs. It says you can just use path_patterns. So I need to write down all routes there which I need in the documentation. But I have quite some different pathes.

It would be cool to have the opportunity to create negative path patterns like

```
...
    path_patterns:
        - !^/_error
        - !^/fubar
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are regex patterns so, yes you should be able to match any kind of pattern regex allows.
Check out ["lookaround" zero-length assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), specifically a Negative lookahead, and try something like below:

```
path_patterns:
    - ^\/((?!_error)(?!fubar).)*$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is an excellent tool for testing and understanding your regex. It will explain the impact of every part of the regex like so:

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group ((?!_error)(?!fubar).)*
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
Negative Lookahead (?!_error)
Assert that the Regex below does not match
_error matches the characters _error literally (case sensitive)
Negative Lookahead (?!fubar)
Assert that the Regex below does not match
fubar matches the characters fubar literally (case sensitive)
. matches any character (except for line terminators)
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```